# Showing inequality $(\lambda x_1 +(1-\lambda)y_1)^t(\lambda x_2 + (1-\lambda)y_2)^{1-t}\le\lambda x_1^t x_2^{1-t}+(1-\lambda)y_1^t y_2^{1-t} $

Tags: inequality

I want to show that
$$(\lambda x_1 +(1-\lambda)y_1)^t(\lambda x_2 + (1-\lambda)y_2)^{1-t}\le\lambda x_1^t x_2^{1-t}+(1-\lambda)y_1^t y_2^{1-t} $$
for all $\lambda,t\in[0,1]$. and the relationship between $\lambda$ and $t$ is unknown -- can be equal or not equal to each other.

At first I thought I could use Holder's inequality, but it seems I got it wrong.

Is there a way to prove this equality is true?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

By Holder for positives $x_i$ and $y_i$ we obtain:
$$(\lambda x_1 +(1-\lambda)y_1)^t(\lambda x_2 + (1-\lambda)y_2)^{1-t}\geq$$
$$\geq\left(\left((\lambda x_1)^t(\lambda x_2)^{1-t}\right)^{\frac{1}{t+1-t}}+(((1-\lambda)y_1)^t((1-\lambda)y_2)^{1-t})^{\frac{1}{t+1-t}}\right)^{t+1-t}=$$
$$=\lambda x_1^t x_2^{1-t}+(1-\lambda)y_1^t y_2^{1-t},$$
which says that we got a reversed inequality.